# Is it possible to filter out zero values in formatted string literals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-literals

Formatted string literals (:+) are used to show the sign of a number (+ or -). e.g:

```
a = 2

b = -5

print(f"{a+b:+}")

output: -3
```

or

```
a = 2

b = 5

print(f"{a+b:+}")

output: +7
```

If the output is 0, it is given as +0.

Is there a way in which if the sum of **a** and **b** is 0, the output should return nothing (I'm not sure what that would mean), or maybe output an empty string?

Example: **Gn = c + (a-b)**

If **a** is **3** and **b** is **3** as well, the output should be **Gn = c. Not Gn=c+0**

I have tried to apply some conditional statement wrt 0, to return an empty string instead but Formatted string literals (:+) only work on integers.

Comment: _to return an empty string_ You are not returning anything here but I guess in the actual code you are. You could do something like: `return f"{a+b:+}" if a+b else ""`.

Comment: now without implementing and using your own type, I believe, and that would really be an overengineered solution. Probably just wrap the formatting in a function that checks if the value is 0 or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way in which if the sum of a and b is 0, the output should return nothing (I'm not sure what that would mean), or maybe output an empty string?

Make a format helper.  Non-zero is considered True, so you can return an empty string if the number is false:

```py
def fmt(i):
    return f'{i:+}' if i else ''

a = 1
for b in range(3):
    print(f'result: {fmt(a-b)}')
```

Output:

```
result: +1
result: 
result: -1
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'm totally following, but in your case, maybe just do the computation and branch on that:

```
c = 1
a = 2
b = 3
a_minus_b = a - b
if a_minus_b:
    print(f"Gn = {c} + ({a} - {b})")
else:
    print(f"Gn = {c}")
```

Of course this could be done more fancily (if less readably), e.g.

```
print(f"Gn = {c} + ({a} - {b})" if a_minus_b else f"Gn = {c}")
```

or

```
print(f"Gn = {c}" + f" + ({a} - {b})" if a_minus_b else "")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could insert a conditional statement to check sum of both variables, and if if the sum is zero you can print an empty string literals or else you can print the actual value.

```
a = 2
b = -3

if a + b == 0:
    print(f"")
else:
    print(f"{a+b:+}")
```